# np.random.shuffle() with seed giving different shuffles every time

Tags: python, numpy, random, shuffle, seed

I have a lengthy list that stores ~127k integers. I want to shuffle the list with a seed for reproducible results later on. However, it seems as though every time I execute the code, the list gets re-shuffled. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(5)
np.random.shuffle(labels)
print(labels[:5])
```

The print statement at the end gives different results on each run, e.g.:

```
[124802, 178520, 155245, 127235, 146541]
[31595, 120382, 47991, 141687, 62795]
[13991, 67563, 69090, 76243, 184231]
```

I apologize if I'm overseeing something very obvious. Hopefully someone can take a few mins out of their time to help!

Cheers!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. If I run a script with your code (and define `labels` of course), every time I run the script, I get the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recreate a `labels` variable and the result will be the same every time. Here you are just creating `labels` once and executing the shuffling code several time.

[`np.random.shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) modifies your list **in-place**. That also explains why a return value is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Guimoute, this indeed seemed to be the issue, using a copy of the `labels` gave me the desired results.